# Is there a way to export asm file which is unhide all items from IDA Pro

Tags: disassembly, ida

I want to get an asm file which was dissassembled using IDA Pro and use scripts to make lots of asm files at once.

I tried two ways to get asm file

first one was with idapython:

```
idc.GenerateFile(idc.OFILE_ASM, idc.GetInputFile()+".asm", 0, idc.BADADDR, 0)
```

generated asm file successfully but that file had some functions which was hided

like this:

```
; [0000000C BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION j__UIAccessibilityPostNotification. PRESS KEYPAD CTRL-"+" TO EXPAND]
```

second one was changed to batch mode to get asm file:

```
~/.ida-6.5/idal -c -parm:ARMv7 -B myFilePath/myFile
```

also generated asm file successfully but I just got same problems that was some functions which was hided

Is there an way to select unhide all and then export asm file from IDA?

Answer (score 0):

late answer
if you don't have a problem to send a keystroke prior to the execution of the idc command

you can define a macro that unhides all the collapsed functions

assuming you are using the gui version open idagui.cfg 
navigate to keyboard shortcut definition and locate the "Unhide All" entry and define a key sequence 
i have defined `ctrl+2` as keystorke below in `ida free 5.0`

```
\IDA_FRE_5\cfg>cat idagui.cfg | grep -i unhide
"Unhide"                =       "Numpad+"
"UnhideAll"             =       "Ctrl+2"
"GraphUnhideGroup"      =       0               // Unhide group
"GraphUnhideAllGroups"  =       0               // Unhide all groups
```

close and open ida for this to take effect

from now on if you hit ctrl+2 and run the idc command you will get an asm with that doesnt contain collapsed functions

foo.asm was generated prior to ctrl+2 blah.asm after hitting ctrl+2

```
auto fp;
fp = fopen("c:\\blah.asm","w");
GenerateFile(OFILE_ASM,fp,0x10127a4,0x10127aa,0x0);
fclose(fp);
```

contents of both file below

```
C:\>type foo.asm blah.asm

foo.asm


;
; ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
; ║     This file is generated by The Interactive Disassembler (IDA)        ║
; ║     Copyright (c) 2010 by Hex-Rays SA, <support@hex-rays.com>           ║
; ║                      Licensed to: Freeware version                      ║
; ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
;
; [00000006 BYTES: COLLAPSED FUNCTION _XcptFilter. PRESS KEYPAD "+" TO EXPAND]

blah.asm


;
; ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
; ║     This file is generated by The Interactive Disassembler (IDA)        ║
; ║     Copyright (c) 2010 by Hex-Rays SA, <support@hex-rays.com>           ║
; ║                      Licensed to: Freeware version                      ║
; ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
;

; ███████████████ S U B R O U T I N E ███████████████████████████████████████

; Attributes: thunk

_XcptFilter     proc near               ; CODE XREF: start+199↑p
                jmp     ds:__imp__XcptFilter
_XcptFilter     endp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify -D option ALYSIS with unset bit "Automatically hide library functions" (0x04000000):

Terminal mode, autogeneration IDB base and ASM file without collapsed lib function:
`"C:\Program Files\<IDA DIR>\idat64.exe" -B -DANALYSIS=0xDBFF9FF7 someBinaryFile`

Or running UI existing IDB without collapsed lib function:

`"C:\Program Files\<IDA DIR>\ida64.exe" -DANALYSIS=0xDBFF9FF7 someIdbBase.i64`

From ida.cfg:

`#define AF_HFLIRT 0x04000000 // Automatically hide library functions`

`ANALYSIS = 0xDBFF9FF7ULL // This value is combination of the bits defined above`